# How to delete a file "locked" by Windows system

Tags: .net, windows

I have this annoying problem when I want to place a new version of my exe overnight on the server (by a .Net program) when some user did not close the exe when leaving office (all users use this exe ON the server).

Simple reproduce method:

- put exe on a shared network drive (Windows Server)
- open de exe op pc1 (WIN7)
- delete this exe on pc2 (WIN7)
  =>file is not deleted but there is no longer a owner of the exe file, not even an Admin; and there is no way to put back a owner on the file because nobody has rights to do that anymore (not even an Admin).
- quit de exe op pc1 
  =>The exe is not visible in open files and not possible to delete the file (Explorer or Elevated command prompt)

I've already tried several "unlocker" tools but none of them could unlock the file because they don't see that the file is locked. But I think the file is locked by Windows system until the user who was in de exe overnight quits the exe; and then Windows will do the real delete.

The problem is that the "to delete" exe is in someway "corrupt" so you can not longer open this exe.

Is there a way (.Net code) to force to give this file back a owner (Admin for example) so that this owner can delete the file permanently?

Remark: because a lot of users use this exe it is not possible to look on every computer if the user is still in the program or run ProcessExplorer on every pc.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A regular delete in Windows is a two-step process. The underlying filesystem file control block (FCB) or link control block (LCB) is first marked as 'deleted'. This puts the file in a state that prevents opening it again. Regardless of the caller, all requests to open the file are denied. It's not a matter of ownership. Only existing handles can be used to access a 'deleted' file. A handle with delete access can 'undelete' it to restore access. If not, when the last handle is closed the file gets unlinked from the parent directory, and if the link count is now 0, it gets deleted for real.

Comment: The real file handle that's keeping the deleted exe from being unlinked is of course on the server. You can force it closed there, which can be executed remotely.

Comment: What you could do instead is have a small program which launches the latest version of your program. Users still using the old one won't come back to a crashed program.

Comment: Of course if you have delete access, you can also rename the file. To minimize problems I would rename it with a numeric suffix before deleting it. Then the new exe can take its place.

Comment: If the file is being accessed from a shared folder on the server, you may be able to use the "openfiles" command line. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/openfiles   .   There is also an MMC snap-in for Shares that can show current sessions and accessed files if you want to view them in a UI. They both appear to have a way to close the connection.

Comment: ..here's another crazy solution. Have a file somewhere on 'the share' called "should_I_quit.txt" and have a timer check it's contents every few minutes (non-lock read!), if the file contains "please die now" then the program exits.

Comment: >Andrew Morton: this is a good solution, in this way we can set also a new version during the day if necessary.

->Davesoft: this is not a crazy solution, I find this a very creative solution with a minimum work to change my program.

So for now I think I will use the Davesoft solution but on long term the Andrew solution unless someone comes with another smart idea  :-)

Thanks already !

Comment: Similar to Andrew's idea - you may be interested in ClickOnce deployment. I believe you can have it hosted in a shared folder. Each time the user launches the ClickOnce package, it will run the latest version of the application. Basically the ClickOnce folder structure has a folder per version of the application - so overwriting existing files is no longer an issue.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/choosing-a-clickonce-deployment-strategy?view=vs-2019#start-the-application-from-the-web-or-a-network-share

Comment: @ErykSun +1 never knew what LCB stood for, was the only one of CCB, FCB, VCB, DCB, SCB, LCB, BCB whose expanded acronym I couldn't locate. What actually is it? I know where the others fit in

Comment: @ErykSun I think it might be for hard links. you can have multiple hard links per file and then multiple streams per link and multiple file object + CCBs per stream. I have now encountered 'MCB' Map control block. That's my new question

Answer (score 0):

You can close network shared file by this method without stop server:

1 – Open cmd (as admin) : press key Win + R, type cmd.exe and press enter
 
2 – Type

```
cd "folder of file"
```

and replace by your file's folder path 
3 – Type

```
openfiles /Disconnect /OP "filename.exe" /ID *
```

where filename is name of your file 
4 – Replace file by the new

Comment: I don't see this command (SmbOpenFile). I have Powershell version 5.0 (build 10586, Revision 63) on a Windows10 computer. I searched with this command:
Get-Module -ListAvailable |foreach {“`r`nmodule name: $_”; “`r`n”;gcm -Module $_.name -CommandType cmdlet, function | select name}

Comment: Try the new method above.